# How to add stackexchange like tags to salesforce support cases

Tags: case, customization, tag, label

I'm new to salesforce so forgive my newbieness.

We use Salesforce to track customer support cases. I would like to add a stackexchange like "tags" feature which will allow us to better search and categorize and report on cases. Here are some specifics

1. Ability to define a master list of tags
2. Ability to tag every support case - ideally with autocomplete like it is here (maximum 5 tags per case)
3. Ability to search and export the cases with the tags for reporting in some third party application, say excel

Is this doable? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce provides two different option what you are looking for.

**1. [Tags](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tag_overview.htm&language=en_US)**

Tags can be added to any object record from record detail page as shown below

[image]

You can add two types of tags to any record.

- **Public Tag**: Public tags are visible across the organization. Any user can use same tag for their own record.
- **Personal Tag**: visible only for current user.

You can see all the tagged records from sidebar link and it can show following layout.

[image]

As you can see you can search for any tag and go to detail page of that tag. Tag has only one limitation that you can't export records and this limitation is currently in idea exchange

**2. [Topics](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_topics_records_admin.htm&language=en_US):**

Topics enhance some functionality of tags. Once topics are enabled from **Setup->Customize->Topics->Topics for objects** you can add topics to any record from chatter panel

[image]

and it will open following window where you can add topics to your record.

[image]

You can create list view out of topic and you can also create report on it which you can export.

For existing organizations, topics aren’t enabled for any objects by default. Administrators must choose which objects to enable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This information is great. I have some questions though regarding this. Are tags free form? Can anyone just enter any tag or can they be limited? Same question for topics. In other words which feature most closely resembles stackexchange tagging?

Comment: yes tags are free form any user can create any type of form and if they start typing for public tags they will get auto suggestion for existing tags. same apply to Topics.  advantage of topics is they can create list view out of it and can create report.